# clickable results from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am experiencing problems to make the results from jQuery `Autocomplete` clickable. First this is what I have in the php file:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);    
$return = array();    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,unique_name,product FROM products WHERE product LIKE '%$q%' AND active='1' LIMIT 11") or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {    
    array_push($return,    
array('label'=>$row['product'],    
'value'=>'./shop/index.php?product="'.$row['unique_name'].'">'.$row['product']));    
}    
echo(json_encode($return));
```

Do I need to add into the array url as parameter?

Is this correct I've done by passing url as value into the array?

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/Lszkb/4/ containing the rest of js and html.. Please help me 
to sort out this problem. I found many questions on this issue but none gave me the answer. And something else - window.location doesnt work at all.. 
Thank you guys for any help and suggestions

Comment: Do you need the multiple values functionality as well like you have in your demo? If not, this is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some multiple issues with object values you want to specify.

I somehow tried to find a solution by passing an Ajax request instead in JSON format.

```
 source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your link",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
```

Replace the `your link` with your while testing it. I hope it works.

Following working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Lszkb/8/

Let me know if you want to approach in different manner, just specify in the comment.